# Website creation options for a 9 year old

Tags: html, css

My 9 year old daughter just told me that she is developing a website to eliminate global warming.  She recruited a couple of school friends to be on the team, is lobbying the zoo to use one of their penguins as their mascot, and just registered a domain name for the site.

Okay, I know a little about the technology, but want nothing to do with the creative design aspects and the HTML/CSS to implement it (other that saying "honey, that looks great!").

Any suggestions of an age appropriate inexpensive software to create the HTML/CSS?   One option is something like wordpress, however, it brings a bunch of baggage along with it which I probably don't want.  Or maybe some other application which just creates basic HTML and CSS which I can merge together.  I don't think she wants to learn HTML at this time, just make pretty pictures.

Thanks

Comment: On what platform, Windows?

Comment: Sorry, recommendation questions are off topic on Stack Overflow. ([This may get you started off, though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors#WYSIWYG_editors))

Comment: This question might be a better fit on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Pekka.  Yes windows.

Comment: check Redactor http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/click-to-edit/

Comment: @Manishearth.  Sorry, didn't know.  There should be a section which is just for recommendations.

Comment: I have an 8 year old, and if she were doing the same thing, I would go with Wordpress. WP is so easy to use and play around with... And no need for any HTML or CSS understanding... All you might want to do is find an appropriate WP template to use.

Comment: I'm thinking a simple image editing program that can import photos, allows you to put text on them, and can export the result to a HTML file might be the way to go. It's not going to be pretty HTML, but that's arguably not the primary objective in this case. Although if they have good photos with little need of editing, something WP-Like might work as well

Comment: Also possibly worth checking out: hosted site creation services like http://jimdo.com/ they have a free plan

Comment: @MikeWeller.  Think I should move it to superuser.com?

Comment: @user1032531: SO/SE used to allow recommendations, but they caused problems. So they're pretty much off topic network-wide (try Quora or something)

Comment: If your child (daughter) know html css then its fine with Notepad ++, or Macromedia Dreamweaver, demo version will also do. If not tech savy, create what ever you want to create in MS word, and then save as 'html'. That will help in the beginning, W3cSchool provide good tutorial for young learner for basics. I hope this will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on the project. But when I think about a 9 years old child, I would make it as simple as possible.

Even CMS like Joomla & Wordpress will offer too many options.

In that case you could try Google Sites (https://sites.google.com/). It's very easy to edit and create sites and nearly needs no foreknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft FrontPage, CoffeeCup Visual Site Designer, Web Easy Professional

But It's hard to recommend for a 9 years old child. may be try [Yola](https://www.yola.com/)